# Which is more "semantic HTML" for error messages?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

We were discussing with a co-worker and trying to decide on what HTML element to use for a form validation error message.

One of us is saying that we should use a span or a div because it is a part of an input field, and the other is saying that it should be a p element because it is a text.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe you should use a `<label>` which directly associates the error message with the input element.

quoting the [W3 <sup>specs</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1)

> The LABEL element may be used to attach information to controls.

and

> More than one LABEL may be associated with the same control by creating multiple references via the for attribute.

---

See also [Error Message: <span> vs <label>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707936/error-message-span-vs-label)

Comment: Apparently, while this is "conforming to spec", it's not widely supported. 
https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/notes-on-using-multiple-labels-for-a-control-using-the-label-element/
http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/mulitple-labels.html

Comment: @KevinSuttle, any idea whether support for this is still as sparse in 2020 as it was in 2012 (the year of both sources you linked)?

Comment: Chrome lighthouse flags multiple labels associated with the same input, saying its confusing for accessibility readers etc. Bah!

Answer (score 3):

WCAG2.0 guidelines, on

> [1.3.1 Info and Relationships:](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#content-structure-separation-programmatic) Information, structure, and relationships conveyed through presentation can be programmatically determined or are available in text.

Lists as sufficient techniques.

[G138: Using semantic markup whenever color cues are used](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G138.html)

And

[H49: Using semantic markup to mark emphasized or special text](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/2016/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20160105/H49)

Based on those, I infer that the only appropriate tags for errors are `<em>` and `<strong>`

---

Using `<label>` in not enough as it shows relationship between the label content and the target field, but doesn't communicate the importance of the content.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, the choice of element should be dictated by the meaning, not by "how and where you want to display" it (as @Babiker suggested). That's kind of the whole idea, not to mention the effects the choice will have on (for example) visually-impaired users (for whom the "where you display it" may be totally lost).

It does seem unfortunate that even HTML 5 doesn't have an element for this. Perhaps 'aside' (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) would be the closest? The spec describes it in Section 4.3.5 as:

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.
>
> The element can be used for typographical effects like pull quotes or sidebars, for advertising, for groups of nav elements, and for other content that is considered separate from the main content of the page.

Comment: I don't think that `<aside>` fits this. it's "for ... content that is considered separate from the main content of the page.", while form error messages are directly associated to the form.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right tag to use for an error message.  It all depends on how and where you want to display the error.  Once you decide on these things, your choices will be narrowed, as tag properties and limitations differ.  But how did `<p>` come in this?

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing into the jar: What about `<ul>`-Elements. If an input-field's validation fails for more than one reason, than you may want to attach more than one error-message to that field.

Example for an file-upload-field:

- The file you tried to upload has the wrong format. (Only *png*, *gif* and *jpg* are allowed)
- The file you tried to upload is to large. (Max 1MB)
- and so on...

The Zend-Framework Error-Decorators for example are using `ul`-Elements.

However if I had to choose, between `div`, `p` and `span`, my choice would be div. Best stylable (Background-color for example).

Comment: ?? why is `div` better stylable than the rest ?

Comment: I guess that's a matter of taste. Of course you could even make a span act as a block-element and mimic the same functionality like a div oder p. However if I would display errors, I would change the bg-color, of the message. This way it can't be overseen. To do so with a span I would also have to change the `display`-property to block (at least if I want to satisfy my needs). Regardless of the element I would fix the margin and padding-properties. `p` has a default margin. That's fine, but in most cases I would change it anyway to another value. So let's say `div` is the beste "base"

Comment: .. at least for my needs and the form I want to display the errors like. But of, course in semantic way a `p` would be also ok. It's always depending on how I want to display the errors. In most cases a block-element goes first for me!

Comment: i understand the need for styling.. I just think that if a tag is more appropriate semantically, one should just style that (*through css as you say, which can even the field*)

Comment: Of course you are right! Semantic always goes in front of styling. However I think at least you have to decide between a block and inline-element. And in this case it would depend, on where I want to display the error-messages. If I would want to display the error directly right of the input-element, I would use an inline-element (propably a span). If I would want to display the errors beneath their input-fields I would use a block-element. But in fact you're right: semantics first! That's what html and css are separated for :)

Comment: You can position block level elements next to each other just fine with `display:flex` or `display:grid`. The only factor for the markup should be the semantic meaning.

Answer (score -3):

You could use

```
<pre>Error</pre>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to a nine year old question with an accepted answer and several existing answers it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. The question was asking for reasons for choosing a tag for semantic reasons, yet you've suggested a tag associated with formatting.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.